# java/android - consistent way 3-letter abbreviation for TimeZone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can I get three letter abbreviations in Java for a TimeZone

For eg: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland").getDisplayName` gives me:

> `GMT+12`

but I want `NZST` or `NZDT`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Seems unlikely, since the `Pacific/Auckland` timezone is neither `NZST` nor `NZDT`.  It has the same _offset_ as `NZST` for some of the year, and the same _offset_ as `NZDT` for the rest of the year.  But it's not the same timezone as either.

Comment: NZST or NZDT either of them will depend on the current time. But you can get them using current time. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone dz = DateTimeZone.forID("Pacific/Auckland");
String timezone = dz.getNameKey(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()); // NZST
```

In your `build.gradle` add -

```
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `DateTimeZone` API is supported on AS?

Comment: What do you mean by 'AS'? I asked to use Joda-Time library. And it works as OP asked.

Comment: I mean Android studio, and Joda-Time doesn't supported on AS.

Comment: @Ibrahim, I just tried and it was just fine. See my updated answer.

Comment: It does work. Not sure if this will break or is it standard answer? I mean DateTimeZone. getNameKey is suppose to return 3-letter code always??

Comment: Joda-time is very reliable specially considering pre Java 8 era.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland");
System.out.println(timeZone.getID());
System.out.println(timeZone.getRawOffset());
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG));
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.LONG));
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
```

I think this one is what you need:

```
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
```

Comment: I did try that. But, in Android it returns GMT+12:00